# Counting Shifts in Merge Sort Error with one array

Tags: python, mergesort

I was trying to count the number of shifts that happen with merge sort when I ran into a problem. When I run the code with multiple arrays, for some reason one of the arrays states that 3 shifts happened when in reality its 4. I will greatly appreciate it if anyone can help me figure out what the problem is. Thanks

```
def mergeSort(arr):
    
    count = x = y = 0
    result =[]
    arrayLength = len(arr)

    if arrayLength <= 1:
        return count
    
    middle = arrayLength // 2
    left = arr[:middle]
    right = arr[middle:]

    leftLength = len(left)
    rightLength = len(right)

    count += mergeSort(left) 
    count += mergeSort(right)
    
    while x < leftLength and y < rightLength:
        if left[x] <= right[y]:
            result.append(left[x])
            x += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[y])
            y += 1
            count += len(left[x:])-x
    return count


arr = [1,20,6,4,5]
print(mergeSort(arr))

arr2 = [4,3,2,1]
print(mergeSort(arr2))

arr3=[1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
print(mergeSort(arr3))

arr4=[2, 1, 3, 1, 2]
print(mergeSort(arr4))

arr5 = [12,15,1,5,6,14,11]
print(mergeSort(arr5))

arr6=[3, 5, 7, 11, 9]
print(mergeSort(arr6))

result = mergeSort(arr)
print(result)
```

Comment: You're calling `mergeSort(left)` and `mergeSort(right)`, but you're only returning the count, not the sorted list.  You then proceed to merge your two original unsorted lists, not the sorted lists, and you're bound to get the wrong answer.  You need to rewrite your code to return two results, both the count and the newly sorted list.

Comment: @FrankYellin I think they could insteaad also write back into `arr` instead of building `result`, right?

Answer (score 1):

You have two bugs:

- Your `len(left[x:])-x` subtracts `x` twice.
- You're not actually sorting the given array but just building a `result` that you never use. The sorting is important for the upper call levels to count correctly.

Fixed and with better testing ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVLLboMwELzzFXsMqquE0PQRhX5Bbz0iDk4wiSWwkXFa@Pp0vSaAVbUIEpiZHa/H2w72olX62prbrTK6AWmFsVrXHcim1cbCSTdHqbiVWnVRVIoKGmHO4hO5FTcm3keAF/2c9FVZyKDHZ8BnQyiK@PAh1NleEKuForKIOFkF9CGDxPu5ywh7Ncq7zos0sixrgU7LwvUatsTWorKey/deWRBu5PlyJzy@L6KpIujOAfFcFHCEjL373T5kizyoFP5il8WVNvBtMGyQCgxXZ7Fa7CeeQ8CEMMos6AVrezgsO@eqpM@8L1yIJM6HYrYZDyKnNQvaDakDQe/6TSZI1J34x@G@SKAYQosgiSlceIQ@@nXCfrgUl19iMVijpLs2Kw7vcKTkOMMXqYLZdDUMtnHsfazolvMp@lac3ADM/qN9d60dHg41ca2RCk9tVGSjB5v@PcPAjzMtmCfYwobBM4MnBrsiHmH8SJFhkEwQKv2N6HZCtwSlnpi1Dt4RuCPzBA2T2Ssl/MVhDN6K@Hb7AQ)):

```
from itertools import combinations

def mergeSort(arr):
    
    count = x = y = 0
    arrayLength = len(arr)

    if arrayLength <= 1:
        return count
    
    middle = arrayLength // 2
    left = arr[:middle]
    right = arr[middle:]

    leftLength = len(left)
    rightLength = len(right)

    count += mergeSort(left) 
    count += mergeSort(right)

    for write in range(arrayLength):
        if y == rightLength or x < leftLength and left[x] <= right[y]:
            arr[write] = left[x]
            x += 1
        else:
            arr[write] = right[y]
            y += 1
            count += len(left) - x
    return count


def naive(arr):
    return sum(a > b for a, b in combinations(arr, 2))

def test(arr):
    expect = naive(arr)
    result = mergeSort(arr)
    print(result == expect, expect, result, arr)

test([1, 20, 6, 4, 5])
test([4, 3, 2, 1])
test([1, 1, 1, 2, 2])
test([2, 1, 3, 1, 2])
test([12, 15, 1, 5, 6, 14, 11])
test([3, 5, 7, 11, 9])
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume your question really isn't about counting the recursion and more about figuring out why your algorithm is not correct.  When you're checking for `while x < leftLength and y < rightLength:` you are dropping items at the end of one of the lists.  This should be an `or` not an `and` to make sure you are doing ALL items in both left and right lists.  Something like this:

```
    while x < leftLength or y < rightLength:
        if x == leftLength:
            result.append(right[y])
            y += 1
            continue
        if y == rightLength:
            result.append(left[x])
            x += 1
            continue
        if left[x] <= right[y]:
            result.append(left[x])
            x += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[y])
            y += 1
    return result
```

and you can't return the counts like Frank said because you stop doing the merge sort, and writing back to arr doesn't work in python as it's not an in/out variable.   You would have to have a global variable outside the class to do the counting.

Comment: Both the title and the first sentence focus on the counting, though. And their loop stopping early when the counting is completed is another indication that this is really about the counting. Not clear what you mean with your last paragraph, both solutions suggested there do work (I've posted mine now) and you don't need a global variable outside.